# How to create an application in .NET to be able to run on Linux or other Operating Systems

Tags: .net, mono, cross-platform

I have heard that applications created in .net can be run on linux and other operating system using mono framework. Up to what extent it is true.

How it makes an application platform independent. How monoframework recognizes dll's of .net

How can i host my site created in asp.net to be hosted on linux server. What all softwares do I need if it is possible.

[See this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cross-platform/mono-merta.aspx), is it the same thing I am looking for. It is talking about creating services rather than hosting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mono is an open-source implementation of the .NET run-time, along with open-source tools for the C# language (and VB.NET to some extent).  You ask how mono can run .NET apps--the answer is that mono (mostly) runs just like Microsoft .NET, with the exception of a subset of supported libraries and APIs.

[Take a look at mono's site](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET) for details about hosting ASP.NET apps on the mono runtime, and also [MoMA (the mono migration analyzer)](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) to inspect your .NET projects for mono compatibility.

Comment: Does it means that .net application can be supported on other OS up to certain limit. It doesn't assures that what we are creating will run on all platforms ?

Comment: Mono code runs on both the platforms. As long as you remain in the mono framework, you're assured your code will run on all the platforms on which mono is available.

Comment: @Hasan: i am talking about the reverse. I am taking about creating an application in .net and run in mono.

Comment: @Shantanu: You can develop app in VS under Windows and run on Mono under Linux. You need just to test your app against Mono before deploy. And take in mind some of Mono specificity